# TwilioChatClientDelegate should be conformed to by parent or child?

Tags: ios, twilio

**Context:**

`Parent` is the view controller that displays a list of channels that the user is subscribed to
`Child` is the view controller that displays a channel's conversation. The user goes in it to send messages.

Currently, I have `Parent` conforming to `TwilioChatClientDelegate`, which gives me the function `chatClient(synchronizationStatusChanged)`. I need this to pull a list of channels by calling the following:

```
func chatClient(_ client: TwilioChatClient!, synchronizationStatusChanged status: TCHClientSynchronizationStatus) {
        if status == .completed {
            client.channelsList().publicChannels(completion: { (result, paginator) in
                guard let result = result,
                    let paginator = paginator else {
                        print ("Error fetching channels")
                        return
                }
                if (result.isSuccessful()) {
                    for channel in paginator.items() {
                        print("Channel: \(channel.friendlyName)")
                    }
                    print ("done channeling")
                }
            })
```

As a result, I also initialize the `TwilioChatClient` here.

**Question:**

My source of confusion is: **I also need my `Child` to conform to `TwilioChatClientDelegate`**, because I need it to subscribe to all the messages that is being sent inside the channel through the function `chatClient(messageAdded)`

Having both `Parent` and `Child` subscribing to the delegate is obviously a lot of overhead and sub-optimal. However, just having the `Parent` be the delegate raises the issue of how to have the `Child` receive the necessary messages inside that channel.

Any guidnance on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd approach this by creating a specialized class, say `TwilioChatManager` - it's purpose would be to manage everythin related to Twilio to offload this code from view controllers. This class would also conform to `TwilioChatClientDelegate` and be `TwilioClient`s delegate. Then I'd add two custom protocols, one with methods required by the `Parent` and one with those required by `Child`.  The manager would have two delegate properties, and would delegate from Twilio to its respective delegates - there is a chance to do some preprocessing of the data here and pass obly what's required down the line.

Comment: This is a great idea to offloading the burden from the view controllers, while simultaneously allowing both `Parent` and `Child` to have access to the functions needed to display the relevant data. Thanks for the suggestion!